# Failed to launch JVM after using jpackage to create exe

Tags: java, javafx, jpackage

After creating the `.exe` file using the command `jpackage`, I'm getting the error `Failed to launch JVM` when running the file. What is more weird is that I tried the same command (I keep a file with all the commands for easier use in future) for an older project that I know it was working because a few days ago I made it, and I'm now getting the same error.

The only change that I can think of is that I switched from Windows 10 to Windows 11, but Eclipse is running fine, as well as all my developing tools, and all the other programs that I made in the past (which they should, as all the required files are local to the their folder, the way `jpackage` works).

When running the command I'm not getting any errors, the `.exe` file is created and the installation doesn't have any problems.

What can be the cause of it and what should I do? I've seen a different thread and someone suggested to that person to use `--win-console` and to tell what he sees if anything, but if I use that instead of `--win-menu`, a terminal window is opened and closes without any output inside it.

```
jpackage -t exe --name "Exe Name"
--vendor "Vendor Name"
--app-version 1.0
--input "Location of the jar file"
--dest "Where the exe for installation to be placed, I normally use same as jar for organization reason"
--main-jar "Jar Name.jar"
--icon "Location of the icon file.ico"
--module-path "Where the jmods are located, downloaded from https://openjfx.io"
--add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web --win-shortcut --win-menu
```

Comment: open CMD.exe, change to your app install  dir, run your app exe. Find any error message output ?

Comment: No, it just launches the app and I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using [Eclipse Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/) for both **JDK** as well as **JRE**. Also I downloaded the jmods from [JavaFX Gluon website](https://download2.gluonhq.com/openjfx/17.0.7/openjfx-17.0.7_windows-x64_bin-jmods.zip). Right now I'm using version 17 which has the longest LTS for now.

These are the steps that I did to make it work:

- Download Eclipse Adoptium JDK, JRE and install them (I choose .msi versions);
- Go to JavaFX Gluon and download the jmods for your version (I choose to place them together with the other jmods from the JDK (ex: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\jmods);
- After installing them go to **System variables** and add/change **JAVA_HOME** to the **JDK** folder (ex: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot);
- Go to **System variables / Path** and add a variable to the folder: JDK\bin\server (ex: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin\server);
- When running the **jpackage** command follow this example:

```
jpackage -t exe
--name "Application Name"
--vendor "Your company name"
--app-version 1.0
--input "C:\Programs\Test program"
--dest "C:\Programs\Test program"
--main-jar "Application Name.jar"
--icon "C:\Programs\Test program\Application Name.ico"
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\jmods"
--add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web,jdk.localedata
--win-shortcut --win-menu
```

Hope this will help someone who had the same problem as my, and after running **jpackage** they were getting **Failed to launch JVM** error.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually perform the jlink step before running jpackage; otherwise, jpackage automatically invokes jlink during the process. Jlink generates the executable.exe, but jpackage creates the installer for the executable, e.g. msi

I hope this link is useful:
[https://www.devdungeon.com/content/use-jpackage-create-native-java-app-installers#:~:text=jlink%20vs%20jpackage,-jlink%20was%20introduced&text=You%20can%20manually%20perform%20the,dmg%20%2C%20](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/use-jpackage-create-native-java-app-installers#:%7E:text=jlink%20vs%20jpackage,-jlink%20was%20introduced&text=You%20can%20manually%20perform%20the,dmg%20%2C%20).